# Assign values to a group of columns obtained by regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have this fairly large dataframe with hundreds of features (columns) and I like to access a subset of it using the filter method on the column names:

```
X = df.filter(regex='d2v_*')
```

This works well, but now I'm trying change the values of this particular subset of `df` with a transformation of `X`, for example `X - X.mean(axis=0)`.

I was tempted to use a mask based on the column name but maybe there's a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to this:

```
In [72]: df
Out[72]:
    a   b  d2v_1  d2v_2  d2v_3   x
0  97  19     53      2     29  19
1  74  23      8     80     22  76
2  27  41     72     76     48  62
3   6  90     71     53      7  87
4  21  61     14     64     17  19

In [75]: cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'^d2v_')]

In [76]: cols
Out[76]: Index(['d2v_1', 'd2v_2', 'd2v_3'], dtype='object')

In [77]: df.loc[:, cols] -= df.loc[:, cols].mean()

In [78]: df
Out[78]:
    a   b  d2v_1  d2v_2  d2v_3   x
0  97  19    9.4  -53.0    4.4  19
1  74  23  -35.6   25.0   -2.6  76
2  27  41   28.4   21.0   23.4  62
3   6  90   27.4   -2.0  -17.6  87
4  21  61  -29.6    9.0   -7.6  19
```